# Цикличность в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется 3 блока с классом item. Как через каждые 3 секунды добавлять класс `active` к следующему элементу?

Делаю так, но не работает

```
$(function() {
    $(document).each(function() {
        $(".item").removeClass("active");
        $(".item.active").next().addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
var params = {
  count: $(".item").length,
  now: 0
}

function set_active() {
  if(params.now == params.count) {
    params.now = 0;
  }

  $(".item").removeClass("active");
  $(".item[data-id=\"" + params.now + "\"]").addClass("active");

  params.now++;
}

set_active();

setInterval(set_active, 3000);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item" data-id="0">Привет</div>
<div class="item" data-id="1">Привет</div>
<div class="item" data-id="2">Привет</div>
```

Comment: Цикл срабатывает, но после последнего .item все пропадает

Comment: как заставить его отрабатывать по новой после завершения?

Comment: @asd сейчас....

Comment: @asd обновил пост, попробуйте

Comment: А этот код можно под eq переделать? с nth-child совсем беда получается в коде(( Заранее спасибо

Comment: простите, что такое `eq`?

Comment: селектор в js))

Comment: @asd можно с помощью атрибута. не знаю как в jQuery делать с помощью селектора, а вот на чистом js смогу показать пример. Интересует, или остановитесь на решении с атрибутом?

Comment: Решил остановиться на варианте с атрибутом, но опять возникла проблема( блоки ротируются, но после 3го блока код не срабатывает все

Comment: @asd можете показать, где вы тестируете код?

Comment: секунду сейчас покажу

Comment: Оказалось ошибка в том что скрипт подключался в хеде а не в футере)) Большое спасибо

Comment: @asd не за что, всего хорошего :)

Comment: Не поможете с решением проблемы? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538466/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-div?noredirect=1#comment678956_538466 Спасибо)

Comment: @asd не успел :(