# Цикличная смена фона div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как циклично сменять background-image для тега body?

```
function changeBg() {
    $("body").css("background","red");
    $("body").css("background","green");
}
changeBg();
setInterval(changeBg, 3000);
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос, делаю вот так, код не срабатывает подскажете почему?

Comment: Код срабатывает. И срабатывает ровно так, как вы его и описали. В методе отрабатывает в начале первая строка. Все красится в красный, а затем вторая - перекрашивается в зеленый. Если хотите менять - заносите цвета в массив, заведите еще одну переменную - индекс массива и прибавляйте его каждый раз в функции. И берите индекс этого массива как раз с помощью этой переменной... только как только индекс достигнет предела массива - надо будет её онулять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
setInterval(changeBody, 3000);

function changeBody() {  
  $('body').css('background-color') == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" ?
  $('body').css('background', 'yellow') : $('body').css('background', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

```js
changeBody();

function changeBody(i) {
  var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
  if(typeof(i) == 'undefined' || i > colors.length) i = 0;
  $('body').css('background-color', colors[i]);
  setTimeout(changeBody, 2000, i+1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```